# Setting RMB (Removeable Media Bit)

Tags: sd-card, removable-media

I "expanded" my Lenovo Laptop with an 256GB PNY SDHC card. I would like to show it as *non removeable* disk.

As far as I know there is an RMB (Removeable Media Bit) that needs to be flipped.

I found the Lexar USB Tool "Boot It" but it does not list my SD card.
I found some sources which propose to replace the disk driver but this is also what I would like to avoid.

I have also seen sources claiming that the exact location of the RMB bit depends on the vendor although this is hard to believe for me.

I am comfortable using Linux, dd and a hex editor for this.

Comment: Which OS are you actually using - Linux or Windows? Also why is setting the RMB required?

Comment: I am using Windows but I am also Linux user (e.g. to boot Linux to set the RMB). I want to set it so that it is handled as an ordinary harddrive (I will install programs on it etc).

Comment: On either OS are you not already able to do so? Does any specific program complain when you try to install it on the card?